# secp256k1 and its dependencies as one package

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I use the `secp256k1` library in my Python project. Now, I install it using pip3 with the following command — `pip3 install secp256k1`. Also, it requires the following OS level dependency — `apt-get install -y libsecp256k1-dev`.

The main point is - I want to migrate to AWS Lambda. It means there is no operating system. So, I just need a binary/source/one_folder for `secp256k1` that will have the `libsecp256k1-dev` dependency inside to be no needed to install to the OS via `apt-get`.

How can I compose it to one folder?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda internally uses an EC2 Instance with the AMI ID "amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2", as stated in the official AWS Lambda documentaton[a]. 
To ensure that a piece of code works in Lambda as expected, you could spin up an EC2 Instance, install the required package using the following command:

```
pip3 install secp256k1 -t .
```

After that, you could install your OS level dependency(`libsecp256k1-dev`), and manually fetch the `.so` and `.a` compiled files. You can further include these compiled files in your deployment package, and ensure that your code works as expected.

## References

[a]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html